# How to return data from edge.js func accessing MSSQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, edge.js

This is more a general JS question and not specific to edge.js.  I wanted to play with SQL Server access via edge.js. Based on [the following snippet from its GitHub site](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-script-t-sql-in-a-nodejs-application)

```
var edge = require('edge');

var getTop10Products = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    select top 10 * from Products
*/});

getTop10Products(null, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result[0].ProductName);
    console.log(result[1].ReorderLevel);
});
```

I wrote the following to access my own database:

```
var edge = require('edge');
var _    = require('lodash');


var thingsAccess = function () {/*
    select * from Things where Status = 'A' and Type=@thingType 
*/};

var getThingsList = edge.func('sql', thingsAccess);

var logResult = function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;

    _.each(result, function (thing) {
        console.log(thing.Id, thing.Category, thing.Name);
    });
};

var thingsOfType = function (type) {
    return function () { 
        getThingsList({ thingType: type }, logResult); 
    };
};


var xThings = thingsOfType('X');
var yThings = thingsOfType('Y');


xThings();
yThings();
```

My question is, how can I return results from `logResult` rather than just using the data inside that function?  Instead of the `_.each(result, ...)` construct that now logs to the console, I'd rather have something like `return _.map(result, ...)` that returns an array of Thing objects.  But because the function is a callback for getThingsList, I have nowhere to put the results.

Given how I have structured the code, it seems like my only option is to declare an array in the outer scope and push to it from inside `logResult`.  I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, but I can't see how to restructure.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "return" it, you have to work in a callback, just like the log function is doing.

```
var thingsOfType = function (type, onSuccess, onError) {
    getThingsList({ thingType: type }, function (error, result) {

        // Process if no error
        if (!error) {
            if (onSuccess instanceof Function) {
                onSuccess(result);
            }
            // silently do nothing if onSuccess is not a function
            return;
        }

        // Handle errors using the onError callback or throw
        if (onError instanceof Function) {
            onError(error, result);
            return;
        }

        // unhandled errors
        throw error;

    }); 
};
```

Now you can use it as Array or within each:

```
thingsOfType("X", function (result) {

    // Here result should be an Array
    var len = result.length;

    // You can use result here with or without _.each

    // Do something here

} /*, not an onError function defined */ );
```

Example Usage, and how to go further with the event driven code:

```
var printAllThingsOf = function (type, onSuccess, onError) {

   thingsOfType(type, function (result) {

       // Print each one
       _.each(result, function (thing) {
           console.log(thing.Id, thing.Category, thing.Name);
       });

       // this function is the thingsOfType-onSuccess function,
       // so propagate the new printAllThingsOf-onSuccess function;
       // "call the callback"
       if (onSuccess instanceof Function) {
           onSuccess(result);
       }

   }, onError /* propagate the onError */ );

};

printAllThingsOf("X"); // just do it or fail. onSuccess and onError are undefined.
```

Comment: Thanks @metadings for a clear and comprehensive answer.  I removed a stray right parenthesis from the end of printAllThingsOf's definition.